# How to create pem file in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, openssl, pem

I was unable to install M2Crypto in Windows. Can anyone suggest how can I create a .pem file? I am trying to follow the below piece of code but unable to create key.pem file

```
import paramiko
f = open('/path/to/key.pem','r')
s = f.read()
import StringIO
keyfile = StringIO.StringIO(s)
mykey = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key(keyfile)
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect('myserver.compute-1.amazonaws.com', username='ubuntu', pkey=mykey)
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('uptime')
```

Comment: do you want to do it in python or just want a pem file?

Comment: A pem file should be sufficent. If there are packages/methods to generate pem in Python (without M2Crypto) then I can use it.

Comment: you can generate a .pem using openssl for windows http://indy.fulgan.com/SSL/

Comment: aslo a tut here https://www.digicert.com/ssl-support/pem-ssl-creation.htm